# Can I use VGA and displayPort of my laptop to have triple display?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, displayport

All is in the question.. I have a laptop with display port and vga.. Can I connect one monitor with vga and one Displayport monitor to the Display port to make me a triple monitor system?
I prefer to ask before buying material..

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what kind of graphics card it uses?

Comment: I think this is NVIDIA Quadro FX 3800M..

Comment: The answer to this depends specifically ON THE EXACT LAPTOP - even if the chipset supports it, the manufacturer can certainly dummy ports out.  You need to edit your question with the exact model.  (And please be more specific in the future, thanks.)

Comment: Im sorry but this is a laptop with nvidia quadro fx 3800M.. just want to know if this may be possible.. are you angry? :-(

Comment: @bAN - No one is angry.  But to get a good answer you need to provide the exact model of the laptop itself.  Don't you know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (non-obscure) configurations on the market that will allow you to do this:

- An Intel laptop with NVIDIA graphics and Optimus *and* running Windows 7 (e.g. Lenovo T410)
- A laptop with AMD graphics supporting Eyefinity (e.g. HP 8460p)

Both may require you to have the right docking station though. I can't say for sure there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely end up with mirrored displays somewhere. I doubt the laptop has the capabilities of extending the desktop threefold.

Comment: -1, this is total speculation without knowing what the laptop is.  (Although in fairness, odds are you're right.)

Comment: @Shinrai: I said *most likely*, you seem to agree with me. You warped perception of reality shouldn't be let out on others.

Comment: I don't consider pure speculation a good answer, and it encourages badly worded vague questions like this one to boot.  It really should have been a comment, IMO.  (No personal slight intended.)